# stack overflowの日英アカウントの連携について

Tags: サポート, アカウント

昨日、stack overflow英語版で質問をしました。
というのも日本語サービスの存在を知らなかったためです。
どちらもgithubでログインしているのですが、日英のスタックオーバーフロー同士は連携していないように思います。

連携する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: メタに質問を移動させました。今後はこちらでお話いただければと思います。

Comment: @nekketsuuu ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/36979/higamma

[image]

上の画像のように、それぞれのサイトごとにアカウントが作られ、まとめられています。この意味で各サイトでのアカウントは連携しています。

信用度やバッジなどは各サイトで別々にカウントされます。Stack Exchange には英語版 Stack Overflow や日本語版スタック・オーバーフロー以外にも[多くのサイト](https://stackexchange.com/sites)があり、実績はそれぞれ個別に計算されるようになっています。